# How to read/visualise this confusion matrix?

Tags: r, confusion-matrix, mathematica

I was offered a confusion matrix, which is called *Parametrised 5x5 confusion matrix* by authors where I extracted the values and where the diagonal has the correct results (0 in all); the results are bad, which can be seen in the confusion matrix; they do not understand why; in ideal situation, all values should be zero that is no failures should occur; I would like to visualise the matrix somehow to explain how interpret such non-standard confusion matrix

```
Real Prediction
     A  B  C  D  E
A    0  1  1  1  1 
B    1  0  2  2  2 
C    2  2  0  3  3
D    3  3  3  0  4
E    4  4  4  4  0
```

Claims

1. it is critical to have cells wrong in column(2-5) - row(2-5) i.e. the lower right square matrix; the authors put equal critical grade on all these cells
2. Column A and row A are ok.

### Visualisation attempts

I am thinking if cells of column(2-5) - row(2-5) can visualised individually like in normal confusion matrix, since the deviation from the diagonal indicates the severity.

- Unable to use **fourfoldplot** for the inspection in R 3.1.1

  ```
  # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23891140/r-how-to-visualize-confusion-matrix-using-the-caret-package
  ctable <- as.table(matrix(c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0), nrow = 5, byrow = TRUE))
  fourfoldplot(ctable, color = c("#CC6666", "#99CC99"),
           conf.level = 0, margin = 1, main = "Confusion Matrix")

  > install.packages("fourfoldplot")
  Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
  (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
  --- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---

  Warning message:
  package ‘fourfoldplot’ is not available (for R version 3.1.1)
  ```
- Attempt in Mathematica

  ```
  MatrixPlot[{ {0, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 2, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 0, 3, 3}, {3, 3, 3, 0, 4}, {4, 4, 4, 4, 0}}]
  ```

  - Fig. 1 Output of the Mathematica code where you

    [image]

Fig. 1 proposes me that the critical points are column1-row5 and column1-(row1-4) whch are brightest colored (orange) while the original claim that the whole lower square matrix column(2-5)-row(2-5) are equally all wrong. To claim that column1-row5 is right does not make sense.

How can you classify/interpet such a confusion matrix?

Comment: Are you sure this is a confusion matrix? The columns are ordered 1-4, so it makes me think this is reflecting some kind of ranking rather than counts of misclassification. Also, do you mean lower-left triangle?

Comment: You/they are using the term "Confusion Matrix" in a nonstandard way, which will make it difficult to answer your question for most readers. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix for the usual meaning. They may be only including only wrong classifications -- hence the 0's on the diagonal -- which is non-standard, but the 1-4 repeated in-order in the columns is totally unrealistic and looks more like them ranking something.

Comment: I've googled around and can't find anything about this peculiar kind of confusion matrix. Do you have any links that describe it? Without that, I don't see how anyone can help.

Comment: Are you sure you're not recreating the CrossValidated symbol?

Comment: @Firebug Do you have some proposals? - - Actually, the data is about medical physics. Can you explain what is the story behind CrossValidated symbol?

Comment: There's some confusion going on: the table has two axis, "Real" and "Truth". Confusion matrices are usually labeled like "Truth" vs "Prediction".

Comment: I'm a medical physicist, perhaps just a bit of context could help to elucidate the question. The point raised by @Wayne is also valid, this sounds more like some sort of ranking, like an error cost matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per @Firebug's comment, this looks like an error [cost matrix](http://cse-wiki.unl.edu/wiki/index.php/Cost_Sensitive_Learning):

```
Real Prediction
     A  B  C  D  E
A    0  1  1  1  1 
B    1  0  2  2  2 
C    2  2  0  3  3
D    3  3  3  0  4
E    4  4  4  4  0
```

It looks like the classes are ordinal, with A high and E low and the cost for a correct prediction is 0, and the cost for predicting higher than actual is lower than predicting lower than actual. So if you predict a C as a C, you get no penalty, if you predict it as an A or B (higher) you get a 2 penalty, and if you predict id as a D or E (lower), you get a 3 penalty.

The penalties wrap around, so that predicting high on an E is the same as predicting low on a D, and the penalty for predicting high on a D is the same as predicting low on a C.

Sound right? I think this is being mixed up with a [confusion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix), which normally indicates the number of predictions of each type versus the actual classes. The best-case scenario is all numbers on the diagonal (prediction and actual agree) and all zero off-diagonal.